# Is there a way to intercept outbound messages from SAP PI?

Tags: logging, trace, sap-pi, sap-xi

Is there any way to intercept outgoing messages from SAP NetWeaver PI 7.1 and 7.3? The best option would be before the message is converted to a protocol specific representation (i.e., before converting from XML to SOAP / RFC / etc.).

Answer (score 4):

I guess you mean by "intercept" to trace the outgoing message payload.

You might check out this audit logger module on googe code, that writes the payload
into your audit log for debugging purposes:
https://code.google.com/p/sap-process-integration/ 
Download: https://code.google.com/p/sap-process-integration/downloads/detail?name=AuditLogger.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 0):

Please explain meaning of 'to intercept'. Three, at least, options are available:
1. Just copy any (or specific) outgoing messages from PI, export into some file location or send to special system, without delivery message to original receivers
2. Same as 1) but with delivery to original receivers.
3. Extract messages from monitoring (history)

p.p. 1 and 2 could be implemented via changes at mappings, and so on.